# Ember unknown relationship

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, json-api

I'm currently building software with Rails + Ember 3.12, but hitting a strange issue.

My models are the following:

```js
// test-case-run
import DS from 'ember-data';
const { Model } = DS;

export default Model.extend({
  testCase: DS.belongsTo('test-case'),
  testCaseRunLogs: DS.hasMany('test-case-run-logs')
});

// test-case-run-log
import DS from 'ember-data';
const { Model } = DS;

export default Model.extend({
  testCaseRun: DS.belongsTo('test-case-run'),
  payload: DS.attr('')
});
```

And, my backend is returning the following payload:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "83",
    "type": "test_case_run",
    "relationships": {
      "test_case": {
        "data": {
          "id": "90",
          "type": "test_case"
        }
      },
      "test_case_run_logs": {
        "data": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "83",
    "type": "test_case_run",
    "relationships": {
      "test_case": {
        "data": {
          "id": "90",
          "type": "test_case"
        }
      },
      "test_case_run_logs": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "426",
            "type": "test_case_run_log"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "id": "426",
      "type": "test_case_run_log",
      "attributes": {
        "payload": "SCREENSHOT"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "test_case_run": {
          "data": {
            "id": "83",
            "type": "test_case_run"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've got a custom adapter defining:

```js
  pathForType(type) {
    return underscore(pluralize(type));
  }
```

So, I think that everything should go well.

However, when I get into the ember inspector, I've got the following: 
[image]

It seems that my relationship is not loaded properly. 
And, I cannot access any data, such as:

```js
log.get('testCaseRun') // that is null 
run.get('testCaseRunLogs.length') // it returns 0
```

This is quite strange, as my records are loaded in the store, but not their relationships. 
I have no idea on how to troubleshoot this, since the amount of information I can get from ember is quite limited (there is no error, the format looks good, ...).

Could someone help me to understand what's wrong with my calls? I've tried many things, such as renaming my models, but this does not improve the situation.

Moreover, this model is the only one, which I have problem with. All my other models don't have this problem. So, that's a bit weird.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found the answer of my question.

The problem was that I was using the "underscore" form of the relationships:

```
"included": [
    {
      "id": "426",
      "type": "test_case_run_log", <= HERE
      "attributes": {
        "payload": "SCREENSHOT"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "test_case_run": {
          "data": {
            "id": "83",
            "type": "test_case_run" <= HERE
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

And, changing `pathForType` was not sufficient. 
So, I made my backend use dashes. And, it worked.

Comment: Correct, JSON:API uses a dash as the word separator for all `type` fields, and matches what's used in Ember Data type names. I don't expect this can be changed or configured because it's a core part of the protocol. As you correctly point out, changing the path used on the backend is unrelated to this issue.

Comment: I thought Ember Data normalizes that one for you. Need to check. @RichardViney JSON:API is agnostic about naming rules. It has used dasherized form for quite some time in it's documentation. But it recently changed to camelCase and added a recommendation to use that one.

Answer (score 1):

The `unknown` in `<(unknown):ember264>` refers to the name of the class. That doesn't mean that your relationship is not loaded correctly. It's just Ember Data using anonymous classes.

To see the data of the relationship you could click on that string and afterwards on `content`. Another option is passing the full record to the console using the `$E` link in top right corner. Afterwards you could interact with the record on console, e.g. do a `$E.get('testCaseRun.id')`.

By the way: You don't need to explicitly declare the model name on relationship definition if it's matches the dasherized property name. So `testCaseRun: DS.belongsTo('test-case-run')` is the same as `testCaseRun: DS.belongsTo()`.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. I thought it should be the name of my class when loaded properly. But unfortunately, using the $E helper gives me a null relationship (those are the log and rum variables in the example).

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare hasMany relationship with the model name without 's'

```
testCaseRunLogs: DS.hasMany('test-case-run-log')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem :/